# Wronged query in XQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

i have this XML:

```
<movie>
    <title>A History of Violence</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Another Film</title>
    <year>2001</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
</movie>
```

I would retrieve only the films with year>2002. I'm interested in title and year with XQuery, keeping the tag `<movie>`. 
Example of my expected result:

```
<movie>
        <title>A History of Violence</title>
        <year>2005</year>
</movie>
```

I wrote this:

```
let $ms:=doc("movies.xml")
for $film in $ms/movie
where $film/year>2002
return $film
```

So i get only:

```
<movie>
    <title>A History of Violence</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
</movie>
```

How can i "delete" country and genre from result modifying that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just try

```
let $ms:=doc("movies.xml")/movies
for $film in $ms/movie
where $film/year>2002
return <movie>
            {$film/title}
            {$film/year}
         </movie>
```

For input (I added surrounding `<movies>` element)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movies>
    <movie>
        <title>A History of Violence</title>
        <year>2005</year>
        <country>USA</country>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Another Film</title>
        <year>2001</year>
        <country>USA</country>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

Result

```
<movie>
    <title>A History of Violence</title>
    <year>2005</year>
</movie>
```

Answer (score 2):

Jirka is correct.  Here are some additional choices:

The return can also be formulated as:

```
return element {'movie'} {
        $film/title,
        $film/year
     }
```

Another option is to use the functx library: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_remove-elements.html.

```
xquery version "1.0";

import module namespace  functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "functx.xqm";

let $data := <movies><movie>
    <title>A History of Violence</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Another Film</title>
    <year>2001</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
</movie></movies>

for $film in $data/movie
where $film/year>2002
return functx:remove-elements($film, ('country', 'genre'))
```